# stack not getting updated after performing operations

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, stack

I m trying to implement stack using array and performing basic operations on it. All my operations are performing well. But the issue is when i again try to do the same operation, it seems like they are begin performed on the same old stack and not the updated one after the performing the operations.
for e.g when i push an element in the stack and then try to display the stack , it doesn't display's the pushed element. The same happens with pop() as well every time it shows the same element begin popped out.
Here's my C code for stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 15

int stack[MAXSIZE];
int top = -1;

void push(int x)
{
    if (top == MAXSIZE - 1)
    {
        printf("Overflow Condition");
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        stack[top] = x;
    }
}

void pop()
{
    int item;
    if (top == -1)
    {
        printf("Underflow Condition\n");
    }
    else
    {
        item = stack[top];
        top--;
        printf("The popped element is: %d", item);
    }
}

void peek()
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        printf("Underflow Condition\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d", stack[top]);
    }
}

void displayStack()
{
    int i;
    for (i = top; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ", stack[top]);
        top--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Push the starting element:
    push(2);
    push(3);
    push(4);
    push(5);
    push(6);

    int ch, a;
    printf("Enter Choice: \n 1: push\n 2: pop\n 3: peek\n 4: display \n\n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);

    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter the element you want to push to stack: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        push(a);
        break;
    case 2:
        pop();
        break;
    case 3:
        peek();
        break;
    case 4:
        displayStack();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid Choice...");
    }
}
```

Any idea what's the matter??

Comment: If you add a value to your stack from the switch, you can't see if it worked, because your program is terminated.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to put all the code getting the input and acting on it inside a loop.

Comment: So whats the way to check if it worked or not other than switch case??

Comment: Your `displayStack` function is clearing the stack as a side effect, which probably doesn't make sense.  Just get rid of the `top--;` in the loop.  Even if you wanted to clear it, it would make more sense to just set it to `-1` after the loop, rather than decrementing it one-element-at-a-time inside the loop.

Comment: It would probably make sense to put your interactive portion inside a loop.  Or at least display the stack before exiting.

Comment: @Tom karzes the `top--` is necessary because i have set i = top inside the for loop and to decrement i in each iteration i must decrement top as well . Else it will print the top element only for n times.

Comment: I got a solution , in order to see the changes i need to display the stack once gain in the main function after the switch statement. Then we can see the changes applied to the stack.

Comment: @NeilsonProgrammer That's because you're printing `stack[top]` rather than `stack[i]`.  The function makes no sense.  Leave `top` alone, and use `i` for the loop and the array index.  Try to reason it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `displayStack()` function with this:

```
void displayStack()
{
    int i;
    for (i = top; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ", stack[i]);
    }
}
```

You should not modify a data structure inside an output function. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: i tried it and it always prints the topmost element because the top which is defined globally is already set to the last index and in this loop we are not decrementing it but just decrementing i.

Comment: @NeilsonProgrammer You didn't try it.  You tried a version that is still printing `stack[top]`.  It needs to print `stack[i]`, as shown here and as I explained in my comment.  Try to understand what people are telling you, and pay attention to what you're doing.

Comment: @NeilsonProgrammer that is right, why would we decrement `top` when we could just use a temporary variable instead. Note that I use `stack[i]` to access the stack and not `stack[top]`, so changes to top would not change what we print. Changes to `i` do. You should not think of `i` just as a counter, but rather as the element we are looking on.